# If you convert a Java Long to another base, how do you get it back from the String it was converted to?

Tags: java, math, numbers, base36

After you convert a number to a different base:

```
String thirteenAsBase36 = Long.toString(13, 36);
```

How do you convert the String back to a normal base 10 number?

```
Long thirteenAsBase10 = ?
```

Answer (score 7):

```
long parseLong(String s, int radix)
                 throws NumberFormatException
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html

```
Long thirteenAsBase10;
try
{
    thirteenAsBase10 = Long.parseLong(thirteenAsBase36, 36);
}
catch ( NumberFormatException e )
{
    System.out.println("Oops");
}
```

Your first thought should always be: *read the JavaDocs*.

Comment: +1: The constant `36` can be replaced with Character.MIN_RADIX Otherwise this could look like a magic number.

Comment: @PeterLawrey you mean `MAX_RADIX`